# Can multiple kafka state store replicas be used at the same time?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Can multiple kafka state store replicas be used at the same time for higher availability?
How does kafka state store maintains consistency among all the store replicas?

Comment: There's only one leader store at a time that can be used

Answer (score 0):

You can configure multiple state stores by setting `num.standby.replicas=2`, for example (this would mean two standby replicas).

When an update occurs to the leader store, that update is also pushed to a changelog kafka topic. The standby stores read from the changelog topic to update their stores. They are *eventually consistent*, meaning that they will *eventually* catch up to the leader (normally they're about 100-1000 ms behind).

When the leader crashes, having standby stores configured can drastically reduce the recovery time if you have large state. That's because (after the leader's consumer session times out and causes a rebalance) you only need to wait a couple of seconds for the standby follower to catch up to the leader in order for it to resume processing; whereas without standby replicas, you would have to wait for the new leader to reply the entire state (which can take hours if you have big state).